# Form is still submitting despite returning false Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

Here is my App.js

```
errorMessage=(validator, input, value)=> {
  const valid=validator(value)
  if (value==="") {
    input.nextElementSibling.style.display="inherit"
    return false 
  } else if (!valid && value!=="") {
    input.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.display="inherit"
    return false 
  }
  return true
}

const checkedCheckboxes=Array.from(checkboxes).filter(checkbox=> checkbox.checked);

validateCheckboxes=()=> {
  const checked=checkedCheckboxes.length;
  if (!checked) {
    fieldSetActivity.nextElementSibling.style.display="block"
    return false 
  }
  return true 
}



validateForm=()=> {
  if (!validateCheckboxes()) {
    return false 
  }
  return true
}

// validateForm=()=> {
//   Array.from(inputElements).forEach(element=> {
//     let value=element.value;
//     let input=element;
//     if (input===name) {
//       errorMessage(isValidName, input, value)
//     } else if (element===email) {
//       errorMessage(isValidEmail, input, value);
//     } else if (element===creditNumber) {
//       errorMessage(isValidCreditCard, input, value);
//     } else if (element===zip) {
//       errorMessage(isValidZipCode, input, value);
//     } else if (element===cvv) {
//       errorMessage(isValidCvv, input, value);
//     } else if (element==fieldSetActivity) {
//       validateCheckboxes()
//     }
//   });
// }


form.addEventListener('submit', validateForm);
```

I researched answers similar to this question, and the commented out code, I realized the booleans weren't reaching the parent **validateForm** function.

So I decided to test out one function, which was the **validateCheckboxes** function and implement a possible working solution in my form submit handler. But no, the form still submits despite the validate checkboxes function returning false.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's because you have `action="index.html"` in your form element, when submit is triggered it calls that action. Why don't you use `onsubmit="myFunction()"`, write your validations in this function and if everything is ok you actually submit the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

There are 2 things to be fixed in your code

1. Returning true/false works if you have an `onSubmit=return fun()` in your `<form>` attribute. Since you are using a listener, you need to do `event.preventDefault()` from the validation function
2. Your `checkedCheckboxes` is a `const` which means it will not be populated dynamically when the checkboxes are checked/unchecked. Move it into your checkbox validation method and make it a local variable using `let`

With these changes, your validation bit would look as follows:

```
validateCheckboxes=()=> {
// 2. Local variable
let checkedCheckboxes=Array.from(checkboxes).filter(checkbox=> checkbox.checked);
  const checked=checkedCheckboxes.length;
  if (!checked) {
    fieldSetActivity.nextElementSibling.style.display="block"
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

validateForm=()=> {
  if (!validateCheckboxes()) {
  // 1. preventDefault instead of 'false'
     event.preventDefault();
  }
  return;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/raghav_s/3e6s5tw8/

**OLD ANSWER:**

*Offers a generic "How to validate your form"*

You need to call your JS validation *before* the form is submitted
To do that, use the form's `onSubmit` attribute like this

```
<form action="index.html" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/raghav_s/3e6s5tw8/

You can also do it using a form event listener and calling `event.preventDefault()` as specified in this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event)

Quoting the example from that page:

JS:

```
function logSubmit(event) {
  log.textContent = `Form Submitted! Time stamp: ${event.timeStamp}`;
  event.preventDefault();
}

const form = document.getElementById('form');
const log = document.getElementById('log');
form.addEventListener('submit', logSubmit);
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
  <label>Test field: <input type="text"></label>
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
<p id="log"></p>
```

Comment: @Bob. true, sorry I missed that. I think calling event.preventDefault() should help. I'll try out a fiddle and post one

Comment: @Bob that is correct. I have updated my answer on why that is so and with steps to get your code working